# Django change trans message

Tags: django, django-templates

How to change the text hyperlink to 'Deploy'?

```
<a href="#" >{%trans "LANG" %}</a>
```

I have tried:

```
<a href="#" >LANG</a>
```

I have also changed the messages in .po file and have compiled them..What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change "Start" to "Deploy" and run

```
./manage.py makemessages -l <LANGUAGE CODE>
```

or

```
django-admin.py makemessages -a
```

for all languages
It will generate new .po-file

then

```
./manage.py compliemessages
```

And it should be fine. Don't forget to restart web-server.